# How to make the current time appear in an alert box

Tags: javascript, html, time

How does one make the current time appear in an alert box? I'm new to programming, so I'm completely lost. I'm coding in html5 or javascript. I've added most of my code here.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
    function startTime(){
        var today=Date();
        var h=today.getHours();
        var m=today.getMinutes();
        var s=today.getSeconds(); 
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s; 
    }

</script>
<div id="txt"></div>

<h1>What would you like it to say?</h1>

    <p>Commmon Requests:</p>

    <form action="">
    <select name="requests" onchange ="checkIfOther();" id="dropDown1">
    <option value="blank"> </option>
    <option value="good morning sir">Good Morning Sir</option>
    <option value="current time">Current Time</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>    
    </select>
    </form>

    </p>
<button onclick="mySubmit()" value>Submit</button>

    <div id="other" style="display:none">
        <br><br><label>Optional Request: </label><input type="text" id="otherText"/>
    </div>

</body>
</html>

<script>
    function checkIfOther(){
        a=document.getElementById("dropDown1");        
        if(a.value == "other"){           
            document.getElementById("other").setAttribute("style","display:inline");
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("other").setAttribute("style","display:none");
            }
    }   
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function mySubmit(){
        var x=document.getElementById("dropDown1");
        if(x.value == "other"){
            alert("You have chosen: " + otherText.value); 
        }
        else if(x.value == "current time"){
            alert("The current time is: " + 'txt'.value); //what do I do here?
        }
        else{   
            alert("You have chosen: " + x.options[x.selectedIndex].text);
        }   
    }   
</script>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML instead of 'txt'.value. innerHTML can be used for both setting and getting the value.

Comment: *`'txt'.value //what do I do here?`* - We'd like to know as well. Why don't you just `return` the string from `startTime`, call that, and put the result into the alert?

Comment: have a look @ http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Incomplete code provide though

Comment: @Amine unfortunately that didn't work

Comment: @Bergi, how do I do that?

Comment: where is `otherText` defined at ? and i'm pretty sure this is illegal `alert("The current time is: " + 'txt'.value);`

Comment: @user2542058: I'll make it an answer. Could you show us how you are calling those `mySubmit` and `startTime` functions?

Comment: @user2542058 scripts shouldn't be outside the `<body>` and `<html>`tag. instead you should append scripts outside the `<html>` tag to the `<body>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your HTML is completely screwed. Validate it.

As for the code itself, `startTime` is broken. It needs `new Date()`.

```
function startTime(){
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds(); 
  return [ h, m, s ].join(':')
}
```

and to get it into an alert box you can just do:

```
alert(startTime());
```

If you want to put it in an element like `<div id="txt"></div>` you can do:

```
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = startTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
...
else if(x.value == "current time"){
    startTime();
    alert("The current time is: " + document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a function `getTime` that returns the current time string:

```
function getTime(){
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds(); 
    return h+":"+m+":"+s; 
}
```

Then use that:

```
…
else if(x.value == "current time"){
    alert("The current time is: " + getTime());
}
…
```

If you still need the `startTime` function, you can use it there as well:

```
function startTime() {
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = getTime();
}
```